# TypeError: Cannot read property "values" from undefined. onEdit @ ClosedTSR.gs:3

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

```
// When Form Gets edited

function onEdit(e) {
    var Timestamp = e.values[2];
    var email_sender = e.values[3];
    var email_address = "";
    var TSRNumber = e.values[19];
    var IssueType = e.values[4];
    var Region = e.values[0]; 
    var Customer = e.values[5];
    var ShortName = e.values[6];      
    var City = e.values[9];
    var State = e.values[10];
    var Contact = e.values[11];
    var Product = e.values[12];   
    var TankCode = e.values[13]; 
    var ProbDesc = e.values[14];
    var Terminal = e.values[1];
    var Priority = e.values[18];
    var TSRStatus = e.values[22];

// Check if TSR is Closed 

    if(TSRStatus == "Closed"){

    switch (Region) {   
    case "East":        
    email_address = xxxxxxxx
```

Basically when a user changes a cell value to "Closed" I am trying to send an email containing information from that specific row.

Comment: you should format that code

Comment: You're right, I fixed it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no values array in an onEdit trigger event object.  There is for an onFormSubmit trigger.

[event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

I recommend reading before coding or at least during coding